# Postgres: how to find absent users in DB

Tags: postgresql

Regular tasks when need to compare two db. Somene has sent me list of users, that should be in my database. 127 positions.

When I make `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (...list of sent ids)` I find only 100 users.

How do I select those, who are in the list, but not in my database?

I've trying something like this:

```
    SELECT id FROM
  (SELECT '089477','089485','089417','089419','089416','089415','082513','087201','084769','083467','089498','089394','085097','084818','089497','085208','082924','087204','087257','084708','0844187','089119','088475','089448','084824','089436','085200','086431','089444','089479','089486','089460','089442','089449','089413','089420','084917','084702','089433','089437','089443','081804','088813','089480','089441','087184','081806','089435','081784','089401','089434','089423','089384','089422','089382','089476','089473','089406','089461','089404','089409','089410','089412','089411','089396','089006','089381','089379','089378','089397','089405','080006','089293','089478','084846','085210','089453','089400','089452','089389','089383','089456','089402','089394','089418','089392','089387','089399','089101','089117','080163','086021','081059','089414','089108','089288','089447','089446','089388','089445','089386','089430','088828','088375','089407','083429','088645','089377','089342','089337','089332','081635','089426','087197','089425','087767','088395','089341','089349','082114','082123','084687','089333','089297','087371','089331') as all_users

WHERE id NOT IN(
SELECT trader_systems_id as id FROM users WHERE
  trader_systems_id IN (
    '089477','089485','089417','089419','089416','089415','082513','087201','084769','083467','089498','089394','085097','084818','089497','085208','082924','087204','087257','084708','0844187','089119','088475','089448','084824','089436','085200','086431','089444','089479','089486','089460','089442','089449','089413','089420','084917','084702','089433','089437','089443','081804','088813','089480','089441','087184','081806','089435','081784','089401','089434','089423','089384','089422','089382','089476','089473','089406','089461','089404','089409','089410','089412','089411','089396','089006','089381','089379','089378','089397','089405','080006','089293','089478','084846','085210','089453','089400','089452','089389','089383','089456','089402','089394','089418','089392','089387','089399','089101','089117','080163','086021','081059','089414','089108','089288','089447','089446','089388','089445','089386','089430','088828','088375','089407','083429','088645','089377','089342','089337','089332','081635','089426','087197','089425','087767','088395','089341','089349','082114','082123','084687','089333','089297','087371','089331'
  )
)
```

but no luck guessing.

Comment: Can you post the table formats? (with the columns)

Comment: It doesn really matters, lets say we have only on column - Id. And I got list as a text of ids that should be in my database. Some of them are in there, but some not. I can easily find which are IN, but how to find missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer join to a values list:

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM (
  values 
     ('089477'),('089485'),('089417'),('089419'),('089416'),('089415'),('082513'),('087201'),('084769'),('083467'),('089498'),
     ('089394'),('085097'),('084818'),('089497'),('085208'),('082924'),('087204'),('087257'),('084708'),('0844187'),('089119'),
     ('088475'),('089448'),('084824'),('089436'),('085200'),('086431'),('089444'),('089479'),('089486'),('089460'),('089442'),
     ('089449'),('089413'),('089420'),('084917'),('084702'),('089433'),('089437'),('089443'),('081804'),('088813'),('089480'),
     ('089441'),('087184'),('081806'),('089435'),('081784'),('089401'),('089434'),('089423'),('089384'),('089422'),('089382'),
     ('089476'),('089473'),('089406'),('089461'),('089404'),('089409'),('089410'),('089412'),('089411'),('089396'),('089006'),
     ('089381'),('089379'),('089378'),('089397'),('089405'),('080006'),('089293'),('089478'),('084846'),('085210'),('089453'),
     ('089400'),('089452'),('089389'),('089383'),('089456'),('089402'),('089394'),('089418'),('089392'),('089387'),('089399'),
     ('089101'),('089117'),('080163'),('086021'),('081059'),('089414'),('089108'),('089288'),('089447'),('089446'),('089388'),
     ('089445'),('089386'),('089430'),('088828'),('088375'),('089407'),('083429'),('088645'),('089377'),('089342'),('089337'),
     ('089332'),('081635'),('089426'),('087197'),('089425'),('087767'),('088395'),('089341'),('089349'),('082114'),('082123'),
     ('084687'),('089333'),('089297'),('087371'),('089331')
) as t(id)
  left join users u on t.id = u.trader_systems_id 
where u.trader_systems_id  is null;
```

You can also return found and not found users:

```
select t.id, 
       u.*,
from (
   values ( .... )
) as t(id)
  left join users u on t.id = u.trader_systems_id;
```

---

If you get a single string with comma separated IDs, you can use `unnest()` and `string_to_array()` to turn that in a proper set:

```
select t.id, 
       u.*,
from unnest(string_to_array('089477,089485,089417,089419,089416,..', ',',  null)) as t(id)
  left join users u on t.id = u.trader_systems_id;
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! But is that possible to make this select work without brackets? :) I mean I usually get just list if ids, comma separeted.

Comment: I got the idea, but still cant make it work - ids in my case are strings, so what I have is a string `'234', '2324'` not `'234, 2342'` - anyway, my pg says there is a mistake somewhere close to `as` - and Icant figure out what is a mistake

Comment: `
SELECT t.id
FROM unnsest(string_to_array('089477,089485') as t(id)
`
Doesnt work. Should it?

Comment: @DenisMatafonov: Then put your original `select` statement where I put the `values` clause in my first version of the answer.

Comment: Ok `SELECT t.id FROM unnest(string_to_array('089477','089485', null)) as t(id)` this does work, but it gives me only one Id instead of two. I simply shold sleep more, thanks for you help man.

Comment: yes, but `SELECT t.id FROM unnest(string_to_array('089477, 089485', null)) as t(id)` - that doesnt work - I get all numbers separated

Comment: Ok, I found oput how it should work

`SELECT t.id FROM unnest(string_to_array('089477, 089485', ',', null)) as t(id)`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot the second parameter in my answer.

Comment: Finally I got it. `SELECT t.id, u.id FROM unnest(string_to_array('089477, 089485', ',', null)) as t(id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS u ON t.id = u.trader_systems_id`

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
select * from [given_list] EXCEPT select * from [already_in_database]
```

This will return the users who are in one list but not the other.

Obviously, without more information it is hard to make use of primary keys, and so forth

Comment: `given_list` in most cases just comma separated ids.

Thats the problem - to make use of select, I first have to put them to db